# Parse text with python RegEx groups with group order changing

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse places names like this:

```
à : Paris (France)
```

But often it encounters a place in USA like this

```
à : Boston (MA) (États-Unis)
```

I tried this to parse it:

```
place='à :  (?P<city>.+) (\((?P<country>.+)\)|(\((?P<state>.+)\) \((?P<country>.+)\)))'
```

But it doesn't seem to work and it goes beyond my current understanding of beginner.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the state group optional using the quantifier `?`:

```
à : (?P<city>\S+) (?:\((?P<state>\S+)\) )?\((?P<country>\S+)\)
#                 ^^^                   ^^
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xOcyOD/1/).

In which case it will match both:

```
à : (?P<city>\S+) \((?P<state>\S+)\) \((?P<country>\S+)\)
```

and

```
à : (?P<city>\S+) \((?P<country>\S+)\)
```